# Truck will not budge 06 f150

Tags: brakes, f-150

So this week end I changed my brakes. Flex lines, caliper, rotors and pads in the front and rotors and pads in the back. I greased all moving parts where they should be, gravity bled my brakes making sure the master cylinder didn’t run dry till there were no bubbles and the fluid was clear and pushed it out of the garage(no reverse)rolled just fine. I pull it along side of the garage and the next morningh I cat get it to move, at all. Not forwards,backwards, nothing. Since its around 25 degrees out now and was 14 last night, could the cold be the problem?mabey making the shoes stick? Or did I mess something up? I’m in no way a professional mechanic, but I’ve never taken a vehicle if mine In to a shop. I’m an avid ‘DIY’er.so I HAVE to figure this out. any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've not heard of this before, but I think the first thing I'd do is jack up each wheel and see which one(s) are frozen, then take off the brake assembly and see if you can get it to release. Just where I'd start.

Comment: How to get the brake assembly to release? By compressing the caliper? Then there is still an underlying issue.